# Div filled with background color as topbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a horizontal top bar with logo image in the middle of it. Image is on the left of the page and vertically in the center. How would I get image at center of the topbar?
Here is my code:

```
<div class='topbar'>
        <img src="../../img/headerlogo.png" class="topbarlogo"/>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.topbar {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 0px;

}
.topbarlogo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parent div doesn't include all children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424569/parent-div-doesnt-include-all-children)

Comment: We really need more code details, like what is the topbar class inside of, etc. Without that, we cant give a sure answer. Too many variables

Comment: Why does your logo have an absolute position? Unless the parent div is positioned, it will be positioned absolutely relative to the next positioned parent, which I'm guessing in your case would be the body. You can add `position:relative` to `#topbar` to correct that, but I'm curious why you'd do that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the rules for `.topbarlogo` and simply set the `text-align:center` rule for your div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eabmE/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You've spelt your class wrong in the css, 'topbor' should be topbar.

Additionally add:-

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: I'm guessing that's just a typo in the post.

Comment: Good answer, +1. Just an FYI though, in some CSS cases, the margin auto thing doesn't work, especially in older browsers

Comment: I have got the topbar perfectly but image is still wandering somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

You need to clear the floats. Create the following div below:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Should do the trick.